# Can't Find Suitable Xpath or CSS Selector

Tags: python, selenium

Anyone know how to select this via xpath or css selector? The class name is used elsewhere in the HTML markup. Also this div isn't always present in each information block.

I need the following output in this div:

Price: $15.77 (13% off)

Here's the link if you need to see the source code in more detail:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=nav_cs_gb

[image]

Comment: Share what you've already tried

Comment: In the chrome inspection window you can right click > Copy > Copy XPath

Comment: ^highly recommend not doing that. That's a static XPath and falls over frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get required output as

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[normalize-space(span)="Price:"]').text
```

Comment: One other caveat. Sometimes Amazon will use the word "List:" instead of "Price:"

Comment: Hmm... In this case you can try `'//div[normalize-space(span)="Price:" or normalize-space(span)="List:"]'`

Comment: I didn't like either of those options from above :-/ this one is going to be difficult I'm afraid.

Comment: `Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[normalize-space(span)="Price:"]"}`

Comment: This was just an example of how to locate required element. The content (including those prices) is dynamic, so you need to implement Implicit/Explicit wait. You can add `time.sleep(5)` before my code to see that required element found... However it's only for debugging, you should not use `time.sleep()` in real code

Comment: Yeah, I already have waits in the script. I appreciate the help though.